# How to put a link in ModelChoiceField empty_label?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm working on an app, with a form that is a ModelForm. I have select boxes for the model foreign keys that display all the objects of the related tables. Since there are many objects in the table, I would like to display only a few and have an extra option that when clicked on displays a kind of modal with the list of all objects of the table.

My form.py:

```
class ltaForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ltaForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['idagent'] = ModelChoiceField(queryset = Agent.objects.all()[:7], empty_label="<a>Plus</a>")
        self.fields['idagent'].widget.attrs.update({'class': "form-control m-1 d-inline-block"})
        

    class Meta:
        model = Lta
        fields = '__all__'
```

My template:

```html
<form>
     ...
    <div class="row m-1">
        <div class="col-5">
            <label for="{{ ltaform.idagent.id_for_label }}">Emmetteur</label>
            {{ ltaform.idagent}}
            <button type="button" class="btn btn rounded rounded-circle float-start bg-light" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                data-bs-target="#agentModal" id="agentVolModalButton">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-plus text-secondary"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

What I would like is to have an extra option that triggers that modal or popup that I described, so I was wondering if I could set a link in the ModelChoice empty_label to do that. But the way I do it here it just displays as plain text in the html. Is there a way to achieve what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to.

```
{{ ltaform.idagent|safe }}
```

Comment: I tried, it didn't change a thing...